# Add items to ComboBox at runtime?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox

I am trying to add items to a `ComboBox` (say `Name="labelComboBox"`) at runtime when I pressed an add button (say with `Name="add2labels" Click="add2labels_Click"`). But the `ComboBox` cannot show the values I newly added. What did I miss?

The following is the event handler for the add button:

```
private List<String> labels = new List<String>();
... ...
private void add2labels_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    labels.Add("new value");

    labelComboBox.ItemsSource = labels;
}
```

P.S. I am pretty sure the values were added to `List<String> labels` correctly (its count did increase each time).

---

### Updated with workable solutions (3 ways) :

1. Use `ObservableCollection` (@AnatoliyNikolaev's answer).

   Change `List<String> labels` to `ObservableCollection<String> labels`. And only need to call `labelComboBox.ItemsSource = labels;` once in all.
2. Use `Binding` (@HarshanaNarangoda's answer).

   Add `ItemsSource="{Binding Path=labels}"` to `ComboBox`'s properties.
3. Use `Refresh()` (@EliranPe'er's anwer).

   Change the event handler to:

   ```
   ... ...
   labelComboBox.ItemsSource = labels;
   labelComboBox.Items.Refresh();      // new added
   ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [`ObservableCollection<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.observablecollection-1) instead of `List<String>`:

> ObservableCollection represents a *dynamic* data collection that `provides notifications` when items get added, removed, or when the whole list is refreshed.

Comment: What are the differences?

Comment: @herohuyongtao: `ObservableCollection` in this situation will be notified every time a change collection. Please see the link in my answer.

Comment: So I don't even need to use `labelComboBox.ItemsSource = labels;`, right?

Comment: @herohuyongtao: Enough to indicate `ItemsSource` once and conduct operations to add / remove the collection, the `ObservableCollection` itself will notice changes. You can verify this yourself by creating a test project. Also do not need cause every time `labelComboBox.Items.Refresh()`.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `labelComboBox.Items.Refresh();`

Answer (score 1):

Combobox has a display and value member to add values to combo-box you need to specify both.

try this

```
ComboboxItem item = new ComboboxItem();
item.Text = "new value";
item.Value = 12;

labels.Items.Add(item);
```

Comment: I think the `Value` will be automatically set.

Answer (score 1):

I think You have to change some code in XAML to following.You have to bind data to your Combo Box.

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding}" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="comboBox1" />
```